# Using result of a set in a select query in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a select query to fetch specific columns from a mysql table. These specific columns must come from the intersection of the two sets.

Suppose I have two sets

```py
A = {'age', 'description', 'name', 'payment_mode', 'id'}
# has all the column names of the table
```

and

```py
B={'name', 'id', 'class'}
# input column names coming from a file (where values can be changed)
```

Now I do

```
inter= A.intersection(B) 
# would result in {'name', 'id'}
```

So I would want the select query to be `select {inter} from customers`.

How can a write a dynamic query to get the column names to come from the result of the intersection?

Comment: How are you accessing the mysql table when executing a select query? You already computed the desired set of columns, isn't string manipulation all that is remaining?

Comment: If that's the case, you can do `query = 'select ' + ', '.join(inter) + ' from customers'` to get `'select name, id from customers`. Or using f-strings, `"select {', '.join(inter)} from customers"`.

Comment: Yes I just want a query that can use the result of intersection, which is of type set.

Comment: I am using your code
sql2= "select {', '.join(inter)} from customer"
cursor.execute(sql2)
But I get the below error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', '.join(inter)} from customer' at line 1

Comment: Hey query = 'select ' + ', '.join(inter) + ' from customers' worked
Thank you so much :)

Comment: My bad, had a small typo with the second string. I'll update in an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the desired columns in the set `inter`, all you need to do is construct the query string.

In Python 3.6 and above, you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to generate the query as follows:

```
query = f"select {', '.join(inter)} from customers"
```

Or, you can do normal concatenation as follows:

```
query = 'select ' + ', '.join(inter) + ' from customers'
```

Both cases will result in `query` being `"select name, id from customers"` when `inter` is `{'name', 'id'}`